# Как положить QLineEdit в QFrame на PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, qlineedit

Подскажите пожалуйста, как положить в мою рамку `QFrame` два `QLineEdit`, чтобы ввод был именно в этой темной рамке.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit, QFrame, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class WindowInputName(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowInputName, self).__init__()

        self.setUpui()
        self.setForm()

    def setUpui(self):
        self.resize(320, 320)
        self.setWindowTitle("Программа")
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #3f5664;')
        self.fram = QFrame()
        self.fram.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.fram.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
        background-color: #2b3942;
        border-radius: 30px;
        }''')
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=70, xOffset=-10, yOffset=10, color=QColor('#97abb5'))
        self.fram.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        self.user_input = QLineEdit()
        self.user_input_2 = QLineEdit()



    def setForm(self):
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.fram)
        self.setLayout(hbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = WindowInputName()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `QFormLayout` управляет формами виджетов ввода и связанными с ними метками. Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit, QFrame, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class WindowInputName(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowInputName, self).__init__()

        self.setUpui()
        self.setForm()

    def setUpui(self):
        self.resize(320, 320)
        self.setWindowTitle("Программа")
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #3f5664;')
        self.fram = QFrame()
        self.fram.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.fram.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
        background-color: #2b3942;
        border-radius: 30px;
        }''')
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=70, xOffset=-10, yOffset=10, color=QColor('#97abb5'))
        self.fram.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        self.user_input = QLineEdit()
        self.user_input_2 = QLineEdit()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
# попробуйте так        
#        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.fram)
#        vbox.addWidget(self.user_input)
#        vbox.addWidget(self.user_input_2)

        form_layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.fram)
        form_layout.addRow(
            QLabel('<h2 style="color: #A05344;">User input:<h3>'), 
            self.user_input
        )
        form_layout.addRow('User input2 :', self.user_input_2)
        form_layout.setFormAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def setForm(self):
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.fram)
        self.setLayout(hbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = WindowInputName()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]